# Why this github hosted site(http://gitready.com) is nether `User/Organization Pages` nor `Project Pages`?

Tags: github-pages

[Github pages help page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) says there are two basic types of Pages available, User/Organization Pages and Project Pages:
In User/Organization Pages the repo must use the `username/username.github.com` naming scheme and `username.github.com` is the domain of the page, also, the content should be putted in `master` branch.
And in Project Pages the `gh-pages` branch is used to build and publish from.

But in this [list of Jekyll-powered blogs](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Sites), I find [this repo](https://github.com/gitready/gitready), which have a custom domain `http://gitready.com`, seems doesn't meet the requirement of any one of the two kinds of pages(branch name, and repo naming scheme). But do seems hosted on github, according to [this test](http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/graph?site=http%3A%2F%2Fgitready.com).

Is this site hosted on github? If it is, why it doesn't meet the requirements?

Comment: if you create a repo on the web interface and use their automated page generator you can then delete and commit files in this 'master' repo that works as a 'gh-pages' repo. doing it from the command line or gui creates a master and gh-page branch instead. i think this would solve your issue with gitready.com repo.

Comment: I just tested the `Automatic Page Generator`, when create Project page with it, it automatically create a `gh-pages` branch, and put auto generated pages in it. While the `gitready.com` repo doesn't get a `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: the gh-pages branch is the only branch, unless you've created a readme.md file (which would go in the master). so this gh-pages is actually the master so would render the website. Perhaps there is a way to rename the branch then?

Answer (score 0):

First, [since yesterday (April 5th 2013)](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io), this should be **username/username.github.io**

Second, you can have you own domain, with redirection to the right github address.

See "[Setting up a custom domain with Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages)".

> GitHub Pages allows you to direct a domain name of your choice at your Page.
>
> When you set up a custom domain, the server will automatically create a few redirects for you:

```
username.github.io ⇒ example.com for user pages
```

Comment: In my understanding, In order to be hosted at github, pages must be put in a `user pages` repo or a `project pages` repo first, then you can have you custom domain direct to that, but that site(gitready.com) seems doesn't belong to `user pages` or `project pages`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an exception to the GitHub Pages rules (as you point out, it appears to be served from neither a `master` nor `gh-pages` branch), but the server signature still seems to match that for [other GitHub Pages sites](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=jekyllrb.com#last_reboot). Possible reasons for this include:

- [Nick Quaranto](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=quaran.to#last_reboot) is a creator of Git Ready and is also one of the [creators of Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll), the static site generator that powers GitHub Pages, and was able to get GitHub to make a tiny exception for this when it was [moved](https://github.com/gitready/gitready/commit/2d1c7df0a9d359274da0ead48257ba45801890e0) from [his User repo](https://github.com/qrush/gitready) to its own Organization repo.
- GitReady is strategically important to GitHub (encouraging more Git users), so they made an exception to support it outside of normal Pages rules, as it was an early, popular example of GitHub Pages' functionality